# Adding views dynamically to UIStackview

Tags: swift, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to add views(or buttons) to `UIStackView` dynamically.

At first, the `UIStackView` has no arranged views (vertically), and 
after getting from some http response, several views(buttons) are added to `UIStackView`. 
`UIStackView` is also autolayout to hold a specific area. 
I've tried to find dynamic adding example, but failed.

Anyone can show me the examples of adding view onto `UIStackView` dynamically?

Comment: not sure if that will work, I think I tried to do that once and it failed

Comment: What you have done so far?

Comment: Have you been able to solve your issue? If yes please select an answer from below

Comment: All answers are appreciated, but no exact answer for my need. Do I have to pick up one, tho?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may help you. Please follow this points:

- Add `UIScrollView` to your `UIViewController` in storyboard or XIB.
- Initiate an `NSMutableArray` name it `arrViews` gets server response and adds view in the array.
- Initialise `UIStackView`pass `arrView` array in the init method.
- After that `UIStackView` will be added subview of `UIScrollView`.
- Add constraint programmatically to `UIStackView`. That's it.

  ```
  if let response = self.serverResponse {
      if let body = response.responseBody {

          if let view = body.views {
              arrViews =  createSubViews(view)
          }

      }
  }

  let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: arrViews)
  stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
  stackView.axis = .vertical
  stackView.spacing = 16
  stackView.distribution = .fill
  self.scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

  //constraints

  let leading = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(leading)
  let trailing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(trailing)
  let top = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(top)

  let bottom = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
  self.scrollView.addConstraint(bottom)

  let equalWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: stackView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.scrollView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

  self.scrollView.addConstraint(equalWidth)


  leading.isActive = true
  trailing.isActive = true
  top.isActive = true
  bottom.isActive = true
  equalWidth.isActive = true
  ```

Hope it will help you. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thank you. good suggestion. I've not thought of that scrollview at all. I wil try that.

Comment: Welcome. If it will work for you let me know and please accept the answer and vote me up. ;) to help more.

Answer (score 5):

I use this code in one of my projects:

```
    let baseFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: requiredWidth, height: partitionHeight))
    for instrument in instruments {
        let partitionView = PartitionOnDemand(instrument: instrument, mode: playbackMode, frame: baseFrame, referenceView: partitionsAnimator)
        partitionsStackView.addArrangedSubview(partitionView)
        let tab = InstrumentInfoTabContainer.instantiate(with: instrument) {
            self.focus(on: instrument)
        }
        tabsStackView.addArrangedSubview(tab)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! but I can't understand yours for my bad skill.

Comment: its a loop that fills in two stackviews with musical partitions and intrument infos.  The important part is the addArrangedSubview

Comment: I was able to add views dynamically to StackView by using addArrangedSubview - thank you.

Answer (score -1):

While trying with answers, I happend to find how to work it.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var stack: UIStackView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func onBtn_Create(_ sender: Any) {
    createButton("new button ...")
}
@IBAction func onBtn_Delete(_ sender: Any) {
    if let v = stack.arrangedSubviews.last {
        stack.removeArrangedSubview(v)
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}


func createButton(_ title: String) {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)

    stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
}


@objc func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("Button tapped")
}
```

}

And, I anchored to UIStackView, Trailing=0, Leading=0, Top=0, Bottom=8 to TextView.Top

The subviews inside it are intact without any constraints.

Thank you.[image]